# Copyright protection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have some information in my database with legal data that is with CopyRight. I have seen that google books is using some "kind of system" that protects the content to copy and print.

For example this link

http://books.google.es/books?id=C8UMQDBXBQQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=automobile&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PMCLUo-FCce60QW8uYDgAQ&ved=0CDQQuwUwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

If you try to print it (CTRL+P) the book does not appears.

Could you please tell me how can I protect my web content in order to disable the print option as you can see in google books?

My platform is developed using ruby on rails.

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: a print CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Please note that any attempt to disable a browser feature like this is futile. If the user can view your website, there is a way to print it. A simple way to subvert a non-technical user is with a print stylesheet that sets elements to not display.

Comment: did you mean print CSS stylesheet then?

Comment: FIXED! with print CSS stylesheets !

Answer (score 1):

Google's technique is, not surprisingly, fairly sophisticated.  They are not serving HTML or even PDF content.  What you're viewing is images, and I'm guessing that they use something akin to the Google Maps techniques to scroll them, although I've never looked.  But they load these images on the fly as you read through pages.  You could easily take one of those images, say, the **[first page of the preface](http://books.google.es/books?id=C8UMQDBXBQQC&hl=es&hl=es&pg=PR15&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U3MzAaZI-_0LoptjSfb36nahMbRyA&w=685)** and print it.  So those techniques will not only be difficult to duplicate, they will not actually prevent printing.